# Create a trigger for a database in different server altogether

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a read-only view access to a database server s1. Now I'm creating a new database server of my own and I want to update this new database whenever s1 is updated with new entries. I understand that triggers can be executed when both the databases are in the same server but in my case and given my constraints, is it possible to do this?

To follow up: How can I call a python script on a database trigger event?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have read-only access to server 1, you can't change it to trigger anything. Now, assuming you have the proper access to server 1, you can do all of the things you wanted, but beware performance gonna take a big hit due to the cross-server communication.

Comment: Have you looked into: replication, mirroring, log shipping, or always on availability groups?

Comment: Triggers can only be defined within the same database as the table to which you wish to react to changes. And, ideally, triggers do not attempt to access *any* resource outside of their own database. If you want longer range effects, you record that desire locally (using a service broker queue, for example, or just another table) and decouple that activity from the original (table-data-changing) transaction.